# No Class found Error while using BeaconManager

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I am developing an application in which I am using Estimote SDK for the Beacons. I have successfully added the Jars into my project and also used BeaconManager class to check for the status of the Bluetooth of the Device. Now whenever I am launching my application its crashing every time.

Following is my code with the logcat I am getting when the app is crashing :-

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Checking Bluetooth Status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (!beaconManager.hasBluetooth()) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return;
        }

        // If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
        if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
          Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
          startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
          //connectToService();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, " "+"Start Searching for Beacons", 0).show();
        }
```

and the Logcat is :-

```
01-23 12:54:15.629: E/dalvikvm(24896): Could not find class 'com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager', referenced from method com.example.beaconproject.HomeScreen.onCreate
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at com.example.beaconproject.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:24)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-23 12:54:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(24896):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my Manifest File is as follows :-

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <!-- Needed permissions in order to scan for beacons. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this. Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks.

Comment: if you are using `eclipse` did you do an `add to path` to your `jars`?

Comment: yes I am using Eclipse only and I have done this.

Comment: How are you adding Estimote sdk library to your project? External jar, inside libs folder, as an external library project..?

Comment: I have tried two things, firstly I just copied the jar to the libs folder and secondly I have done using the build path, by adding external jar.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse cannot import project well. See [this tutorial](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/wiki/Running-SDK-demos-from-Eclipse) how to do it correctly.

Comment: I guess its due to Eclipse only. Thanks